# How can I add a label left of a checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label

I have this checkbox: http://jsfiddle.net/cdyjt4wo/

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I want to add a label/span left of the checkbox, e.g. "Set Output".
I tried a lot. But nothing is right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">Label</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">

        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>

</div>
```

HTML will load elements from the top left unless you style them otherwise using CSS.

Comment: Yes like this. But the label is above not left. How can I style this using CSS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z58zzu6z/ Check this fiddle, is it on the left for you there?

Comment: Yes. But how can I implement the style from CSS? I tried, but the Label is always above.

Comment: Ok. Do you need me for anything else?

Comment: When I use the CSS style, the Label isn't left anymore. Its above.

Comment: Can you stick your code in a fiddle to show me what you mean? Click 'fork' to create a new fiddle once your code is in there.